# Binding aria-required on host element in Angular component

Tags: angular, wai-aria

Trying to implement ARIA attributes in my custom select UI component in Angular. I was wondering, how the presence/value of required attribute (which might be set dynamically during a page lifetime) could be bound to aria-required attribute on the host element (as laid out [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-required)).

As much as I know @HostBinding there's not such syntax that could bind one attribute to another, except when using a getter

```
@HostBinding('attr.aria-required')
private get isRequired(){
  const reqAttr = this.elRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('required');
  return reqAttr === 'required' || reqAttr === 'true' ||  reqAttr === '';
}
```

although I am not sure it's the best way performance-wise.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if it will work, but perhaps something like this:

```
@HostBinding('attr.aria-required')
@Input() 
public required: boolean;
```

You are going to have to use property binding `[]` though:

```
<component [required]="true"></component
```

Comment: Yes, that'd obviously be a no-problem. I am just trying to avoiid bindings as long as the HTML attributes are involed, but maybe it's just an unnecessary precautiousness.